# how to read sub string containing a key and value of a string containing square brackets using java

Tags: java, string

Have got following string reading the docker logs
Example:

```
xmen logging; xmenID=642c7ded-2fef-4aa3-ba08-0b6ab7f7a5e0; period=[name:search, actions:[start:0 ms, material requests:0 ms, fulfilled requests:329 ms, sum responses:1 ms, total:330 ms]]
```

And using the regex and have got following string

```
[start:0 ms, material requests:0 ms, fulfilled requests:329 ms, sum responses:1 ms, total:330 ms]
```

How to fetch the values of `start` and `material requests` in order to check that their values are not less than zero (using java)?

Comment: Sorry - not a regex writing service here. Furthermore, for parsing complex nesting, regexes really are not your friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you've already parsed out the values into a String, you can simply split and collect them into a Map<String, String>.

```
String valueOutOfRegex = "[start:0 ms, material requests:0 ms, fulfilled requests:329 ms, sum responses:1 ms, total:330 ms]"; // Your String that you've parsed
String valueWithRemovedBrackets = valueOutOfRegex.substring(1, valueOutOfRegex.length() - 1); // remove the leading and trailing brackets
Map<String, String> simpleMap = Arrays.stream(valueWithRemovedBrackets.split(",")).collect(Collectors.toMap(s1 -> s1.split(":")[0].trim(), s1 -> s1.split(":")[1]));  // collect into a Map
```

This will give you a Map<String, String> that looks like this:

```
{total=330 ms, fulfilled requests=329 ms, material requests=0 ms, start=0 ms, sum responses=1 ms}
```